# In Hibernate/JPA how to tell if the ConstraintViolationException is a PK, a FK, or a unique key violation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am developing a generic method with generic handling to persist an entity in the database, however I am having difficulty in knowing if the ConstraintViolationException is a violation of primary key, foreign key or unique key

```
public Collection<T> salvar(final Collection<T> e) {        
        try {
            return dao.salvar(e);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e1) {
            if (PK_violation) {
                handle PK error 
            } else if (FK_violation) {
                handle FK error
            }
        }

    }
```

How do I know what type of violation is my exception (PK_violation or FK_violation)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the exception message to extract the name of the key that triggered the exception. Once you have the index name in hand, you will have to be able to recognize which type of index it is based on naming conventions or based on metadata about your database schema.

Here are a couple of examples from some logs I have handy:

```
Duplicate entry '1023' for key 'PRIMARY'
Duplicate entry 'test-user-817fe6b0-587a-4003-9dec-8d2ea8f87cad' for key 'UKwqsqlvajcne4rlyosglqglhk'
```

The first case is a primary key violation - "PRIMARY" seems to be the key name that shows up in this case. The second is a unique key violation - in our case, our unique key names start with "UK" so we can use this to determine it was that type of index that was violated.

So, apply a regular expression to `e1.getMessage()` with a group for the key name, extract that group value, apply another regular expression or other business logic to determine which kind of index you are dealing with based on your local naming conventions or by querying the database for information about the index.

You can query the database for information about the nature of the index that is mentioned in the exception. If you are going to use a database query, you could do a single query at startup to gather metadata about all indexes and use this cached data for the rest of the run.

If you are using annotated Java classes to specify the JPA mapping, you could utilize those annotations (perhaps with an annotation processor or at runtime via reflection) to extract the information about the indexes. In particular, the `javax.persistence.Id` annotation results in a primary key and `javax.persistence.Table` has a `uniqueConstraints` attribute that utilizes `javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint` to define the unique constraints. Trying to do this at the time of the exception handling would be difficult, because you probably cannot figure out which entity object triggered the violation - in the general case, there are many entities being flushed to the database at the same time; I am unaware of a way to determine which one triggered the problem.

I am unaware of any JPA API that will allow you to extract this information from the EntityManager or persistence unit.

Comment: yes, I thought the same solution, is there any method like: Hibernate.getPrimaryKeysNames () or Hibernate.isPrimaryKey ("MyIndexName")